# Can I publish on Azure a web application with a non-relational database?

Tags: database, windows, azure, azure-sql-database

As I know SQL Azure uses a relational db, on the contrary Amazon SimpleDB is a non-relational one.

Ipotetically can I publish a web application with a non-relational database simply with the "publish to Win Azure" button, as I did with mine? Will Azure convert my db without any problem?

And more, are there any cases where I cannot use the "publish to Win Azure" button?

Answer (score 2):

You'd have to include the database engine along with your deployment. For instance, you can run with MongoDB as your NoSQL database. You can download the Mongodb+Azure project [here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-azure).

There's also Windows Azure Table Storage, which is a non-relational, schemaless data store with 100TB of capacity per storage account. The Windows Azure [Platform Training Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=8396) has a few labs around Storage that will help you understand how to use it.

In either case, there's no magic conversion from one data format to another.

Answer (score 2):

For a non-relational data store with Windows Azure, you should consider Table Storage.  Windows Azure Table Storage is the NoSQL storage option with Windows Azure.

Windows Azure does not "convert" any database or anything like that.